# How do I modify this function to return a 4d array instead of 3d?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I created this function that takes in a `dataframe` to return an `ndarrays` of input and label.

```py
def transform_to_array(dataframe, chunk_size=100):
    
    grouped = dataframe.groupby('id')

    # initialize accumulators
    X, y = np.zeros([0, 1, chunk_size, 4]), np.zeros([0,]) # original inpt shape: [0, 1, chunk_size, 4]

    # loop over each group (df[df.id==1] and df[df.id==2])
    for _, group in grouped:

        inputs = group.loc[:, 'A':'D'].values 
        label = group.loc[:, 'label'].values[0]

        # calculate number of splits
        N = (len(inputs)-1) // chunk_size

        if N > 0:
            inputs = np.array_split(
                 inputs, [chunk_size + (chunk_size*i) for i in range(N)])
        else:
            inputs = [inputs]

        # loop over splits
        for inpt in inputs:
            inpt = np.pad(
                inpt, [(0, chunk_size-len(inpt)),(0, 0)], 
                mode='constant')
            # add each inputs split to accumulators
            X = np.concatenate([X, inpt[np.newaxis, np.newaxis]], axis=0)
            y = np.concatenate([y, label[np.newaxis]], axis=0) 

    return X, y
```

The function returned `X` of shape `(n_samples, 1, chunk_size, 4)` and `y` of shape `(n_samples, )`.

For examples:

```py
N = 10_000
id = np.arange(N)
labels = np.random.randint(5, size=N)
df = pd.DataFrame(data = np.random.randn(N, 4),  columns=list('ABCD'))

df['label'] = labels
df.insert(0, 'id', id)
df = df.loc[df.id.repeat(157)]

df.head()
    id      A            B          C            D    label
0   0   -0.571676   -0.337737   -0.019276   -1.377253   1
0   0   -0.571676   -0.337737   -0.019276   -1.377253   1
0   0   -0.571676   -0.337737   -0.019276   -1.377253   1
0   0   -0.571676   -0.337737   -0.019276   -1.377253   1
0   0   -0.571676   -0.337737   -0.019276   -1.377253   1
```

To generate the followings:

```py
X, y = transform_to_array(df)

X.shape   # shape of input
(20000, 1, 100, 4)
y.shape   # shape of label
(20000,)
```

This function works fine as intended, however, it takes long time to finish execution:

```py
start_time = time.time()
X, y = transform_to_array(df)
end_time = time.time()
print(f'Time taken: {end_time - start_time} seconds.')
Time taken: 227.83956217765808 seconds.
```

In attempt to improve performance of the function (minimise exec. time), I created the following modified func:

```py
def modified_transform_to_array(dataframe, chunk_size=100):
    # group data by 'id'
    grouped = dataframe.groupby('id')
    # initialize lists to store transformed data
    X, y = [], []

    # loop over each group (df[df.id==1] and df[df.id==2])
    for _, group in grouped:
        # get input and label data for group
        inputs = group.loc[:, 'A':'D'].values 
        label = group.loc[:, 'label'].values[0]

        # calculate number of splits
        N = (len(inputs)-1) // chunk_size

        if N > 0:
            # split input data into chunks
            inputs = np.array_split(
             inputs, [chunk_size + (chunk_size*i) for i in range(N)])
        else:
            inputs = [inputs]

        # loop over splits
        for inpt in inputs:
            # pad input data to have a chunk size of chunk_size
            inpt = np.pad(
            inpt, [(0, chunk_size-len(inpt)),(0, 0)], 
                mode='constant')
            # add each input split and corresponding label to lists
            X.append(inpt)
            y.append(label)

    # convert lists to numpy arrays
    X = np.array(X)
    y = np.array(y)

    return X, y
```

At first, it seems like I succeeded reducing time taken:

```py
start_time = time.time()
X2, y2 = modified_transform_to_array(df)
end_time = time.time()
print(f'Time taken: {end_time - start_time} seconds.')
Time taken: 5.842168092727661 seconds.
```

However, the result is that it changes the shape of the intended returned value.

```py
X2.shape  # this should be (20000, 1, 100, 4)
(20000, 100, 4)

y.shape  # this is fine
(20000, )
```

**Question**

How do I modify `modified_transform_to_array()` to return the intended array shape `(n_samples, 1, chunk_size, 4)` since it is much faster?

Comment: Your title and post are asking very different questions. Try to fix this with an [edit]. Is the question you're trying to ask is how to add a dimension of size 1 to an array?

Comment: @Brian Modified. Exactly, size 1 dimension as the second dimension, making 4d instead of 3d.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply [`reshape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) the `X` just before returning it at the end of `modified_transform_to_array()`, e.g.:

```
def modified_transform_to_array( ... ):

    ...

    # convert lists to numpy arrays
    X = np.array(X)
    y = np.array(y)
    X = X.reshape((X.shape[0], 1, *X.shape[1:]))  # <-- THIS LINE
    return X, y
```

or, equivalently:

```
X = X.reshape((X.shape[0], 1, X.shape[1], X.shape[2]))
```

---

As pointed out in [@MSS's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74899648/5218354), you can achieve the same reshaping result also with slicing, by starting from a a slicing where you are selecting the whole array (i.e. `X[:, :, :]`) and inserting a `None` (or its more explicit alias [`np.newaxis`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/constants.html#numpy.newaxis)) in the position where you want to augment the number of dimensions:

```
X = X[:, None, :, :]
X = X[:, np.newaxis, :, :]
```

The last two slicing can be replaced by an [Ellipsis `...`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#Ellipsis) which essentially produces enough full-axis slicing (i.e. `:` or `slice(None)`) to fill the whole array dimensions.

```
X = X[:, None, ...]
X = X[:, np.newaxis, ...]
```

You may want to read the [relevant section](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#dimensional-indexing-tools) of [NumPy's user guide](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/index.html#user) for further explanations on the use of `None` and `Ellipsis` in NumPy's slicing.

Comment: What is the meaning of the star before X in `*X.shape[1:]`?

Comment: * operator unpacks a list or tuple into its constituents. Here it expands the shape slice from 1 till the end. In my answer, I used np.newaxis and ellipses... to do the same.

Comment: @MSS Yes, and your answer is equally valid. I see no reason to prefer one over the other except perhaps `reshape()` is more explicit.

Comment: @noro2 Thanks for appreciation. I am inspired by your detailed answers. How do you manage time to explain and write such detailed answers ?

Comment: @MSS I compile a lot (perhaps more train these days) https://xkcd.com/303/ :-)

Answer (score 3):

Add a new axis to your X just before returning it in `modified_transform_to_array`, e.g.:

```
def modified_transform_to_array( ... ):

    ...

    # convert lists to numpy arrays
    X = np.array(X)
    y = np.array(y)
    X = X[:, np.newaxis, ...] # <---in this place
    # X = X[:, None, :, :] 
    return X, y
```